# cannot get error on expresses app

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing an express app in model view controller pattern. As I am only writing api end points I don't use view. I have only one endpoints and this stopped working the moment I organised in mvc pattern.

Here is my app.js

```
const cors = require('cors');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
var originsWhitelist = [
  'http://localhost:4200'      //allowed front-end url for development
];
module.exports = app;
```

Here is index.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
var app = require('./app.js');
app.use('/', routes);
app.listen(9000, ()=>{
    console.log('server running on port 9000');
})
```

and routes.js is here

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//Routes for offer Rides
var offerRideCtrl = require('../controllers/offer-ride-controller.js');
router.route('/offer-ride/add').post(offerRideCtrl.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Not able to find where I was wrong. whenever I hit the url http://localhost:9000/offer-ride/add , I get the error "Cannot GET /offer-ride/add"

Comment: It looks like you only have a post-route, not a get-route.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: I know [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) is a popular app to stitch together and test post requests (and test API's in general). If you think that's overkill then you can always use [curl](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. You saved my time.